# Python 2.7 custom exception is not being caught

Tags: python

I'm using a custom timeout exception to get around iter(subprocess.Popen.stdout.readline,'') blocking when there is no more output to read, but the exception isn't being caught properly. This is a code that has both a main process and a separate process (implemented with multiprocessing.Process), where timeouts can happen in either. The relevant sections are:

```
class Timeout(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

def handle_timeout(signal, frame):
    raise Timeout("Timed out")
```

This custom exception is caught just fine in the main process, but in the child process, whenever the Timeout is raised, it is never caught despite using (I believe) the appropriate standard syntax:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
subProc = Popen(('tail', '-f', fileName), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, close_fds=True)
lines = iter(subProc.stdout.readline,'')
for line in lines:
    try:
        process_line(line)
    except Timeout as time_out:
        print(time_out.message)
        subProc.terminate()
        break
```

Instead of printing the timeout message and terminating subProc, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/envs/Py2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "reader.py", line 50, in run
    for line in lines:
  File "reader.py", line 13, in handle_timeout
    raise Timeout("Timed out")
Timeout
```

handle_timeout appears to be working fine since the timeout is being raised, but the exception handling is being ignored or skipped. Am I doing anything wrong syntax-wise, or do I need to define a separate custom exception, presumably within the child process?

Edit:

The second code block before was incomplete. Here it is, as it currently exists (with chepner's advice on the irrelevance of iter(stdout.readline,'') included):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handle_timeout)
subProc = Popen(('tail', '-f', fileName), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, close_fds=True)
for line in subProc.stdout:
    signal.alarm(CHILD_TIMEOUT)
    try:
        process_line(line)
    except Timeout as time_out:
        print(time_out.message)
        subProc.terminate()
        break
```

In the parent process (where the timeout exception works exactly as desired), the format is:

```
# signal masking as in last block
while True:
    try:
        signal.alarm(MASTER_TIMEOUT) # different from CHILD_TIMEOUT
        other_processing()
    except Timeout:
        shutDown(children) # method to shut down child processes
        break
```

**SOLVED:**

I've found a solution.

```
subProc = Popen(('tail', '-f', fileName), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, close_fds=True)
while not exit.is_set(): # exit is defined by multiprocessing.Event()
    signal.alarm(3)
    try:
        for line in subProc.stdout:
            process_line(line)
    except Timeout:
        print("Process timed out while waiting for log output")
        subProc.terminate()
        exit.set()
```

Now when the alarm goes off, the timeout exception is raised and caught as it should be, ending the subprocess before triggering the exit condition, after which the child process shuts down gracefully.

Comment: Timeout (or any other) exceptions raised in the other process need to be caught and handled in that process - but I can't tell what you are doing in that process from your code. If the program is just printing the exception to the console and continuing then it's almost definitely happening in the other process though. If that's not than problem, then it might help to give [mcve] a quick read.

Comment: `subProc.stdout` is already an iterable; you don't need to call `iter` to make one.

Comment: @chepner Thanks; I haven't used subprocesses very much before.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually trap an error *inside* a subproccess the way your working your code.  What you think of as error handling using an event to catch or what not is actually a subprocess being raised, executing your code, and managing the response.  Since you are using popopen to manually control the subprocess you need to manually process its response.

When your subprocess ends it should return a 0.  If it returns a -1 or 1 that means an error has occurred you and need to read from stderr to capture the error.

**Edit1**

I see your problem. The way you have it written the handler `handle_timeout` will grab the error and re-raise it every-time. You can't handle an exception in multiple places. As it is you have two separate functions trying to handle the same error concurrently.  This will always produce a conflict and the first one that catches the error will cause your main process to exit. You can do a couple different things here, but let me implore you - do not eat an error for no reason.

fix 1:
   Remove your error handler

```
def handle_timeout(signal, frame):
    raise Timeout("Timed out")
```

fix 2:

```
try:
    process_line(line)
finally: 
    subProc.terminate()
```

The above will guarantee the termination of the sub process without eating an error.  Also, catching the error with a custom handle like your handle_timeout handler is a technique almost exclusively used to deconstruct a complex run or object before re-raising the error. Its a last ditch solution basically for when you have A LOT of clean up after a particular error.  If you want to do that, do not use an `except` block.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, the "try: ... except Timeout: ..." block is being ignored because of the running subprocess?

In case I wasn't clear on this: the subprocess itself (tail -f) is not throwing an error at any point. The exception being raised but (apparently) ignored is within the child process of the python script, not in the subprocess created with Popen (since Popen is non-blocking and the process it spawns has a separate PID, I wouldn't expect it to interrupt error handling).

Comment: Okay, so first things first, if you read stderr after the sub-process closes does it contain anything?

Comment: Alright I see what's going on.  Take a look at my edit.

Comment: See the edit I just made. handle_timeout() is a function that's masks SIGALRM in each process, it doesn't handle the Timeout exception after it's raised (I now realize how misleading the name is, though). Nothing other than handle_timeout should ever raise Timeout in this code (and only when the process receives signal.SIGALRM). The timeouts in the two processes aren't occurring concurrently.

If it were re-raising the error after it was raised, I would expect it to fail in the parent process as well, but it works without issue there.

Comment: I've made the change you suggested in fix 2, and it breaks the child process. The finally block executes immediately after the try, closing the subprocess while the logfile is still being written to (I don't want a single call of tail; I want it to follow continuously), leaving the main process with no output after only a few seconds (if timeout is left intact but only for the main process, then it times out and the program ends; without timeout, it just hangs).